# Playing Games in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: games

I am having a Laptop belongs to a University.

Details;

> - **HP Probook** having amd,
> - 5350 Memory,
> - 7 GB RAM,
> - AMD Radeon x2 graphics.
> - Installed with **Ubuntu 12.04**

I am new to linux.

The thing is I ***want to play games*** on it.

I searched on the net. There are few software like Wine, Playon Linux etc. But I am not able to play with them.

I have also got an advice to dual booting Windows. But I don't want to break GRUB. As I am not so professional in such things and if something went wrong then I would have to pay to the University.

Please help me. I am in great trouble. Virtual box is also an handy application to run Windows application. But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Can you please format your question to make it readable?

Answer (score 1):

## Give up (almost) all hope

...for now. Gaming on Linux is coming, but it isn't there just yet.

Sorry, for my pessimistic tone, but I know some seasoned Linux experts who managed to install their game but:

1. it's for many games a lot of trouble to install and run. If you manage to run them at all.
2. it's a constant hassle with games that require to get the updates working. And the now-a-days online games like WOW, Eve-Online, Starcraft 2, etc. will **force** you to run the latest version.

I'm playing myself Starcraft 2 like this.

In the end you get some games working for some time, but it isn't fun to find out that your favorite games doesn't run anymore need some more lovin' and patchin'.

## Your best bet

If you still want to give it a go. Try [Steam for Linux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve) or use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) .

You can estimate your chances to manage to run your game like this:

- Very recent game will give you more trouble than seasoned classics, like from [Good old Games](http://www.gog.com/).
- More recent indie games come sometimes with native Ubuntu 12.04 support. Some games that are/were bundle with the [Humble Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com) are like that.
- As mentioned: Expect long-term troubles with multi-player online games.
- If there isn't an entry on [WineHQ](http://winehq.org) you are really going to fight an uphill battle.